# Hadoop with Relational Database

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hbase, hive

I am new to Hadoop and would like to know Hadoop works in a scenario.

During the creation of Dynamic Web project, I used to store and get data from MySQL database by sending queries from Java/C#.

I use Hadoop services in my Project and does hadoop provide any in build database system where we can store data and retrieve it when required, instead of using an external databases.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which hadoop services do you use in your project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hadoop doesn't provide any builtin DB. It is just 2 things :

- **A distributed FS (*HDFS*)**
- **A distributed processing framework (*MapReduce*. I'll call it *MR* in short)**

I'm assuming that you would require very quick response since you are dealing with a web service. IMHO, Hadoop(HDFS to be precise), or any other FS for that matter, won't be a suitable choice in such a scenario. Reason being HDFS lacks the random/read capability, which is very much essential for any web project.

Same holds true for Hive. Although it manages data in a fashion similar to RDBMSs, it's actually not a RDBMS. The underlying storage mechanism is still **HDFS files**. Moreover when you issue a Hive query to fetch results, the query first gets **converted into a MR job** and then produces the result resulting in slow response.

Your safest bet would be to go with **[HBase](http://hbase.apache.org)**. It is definitely a better choice when you need **random, realtime read/write access** to your data, as in your case. Although it's not a  part of the Hadoop platform, it was built ground up to be used with Hadoop. Works on top of your existing HDFS cluster and can be operated on directly through different HBase APIs(fits in your case) or through MR(not for real time stuff. Fits when you need to batch process huge amounts of data). Easy to setup and use with no requirement of additional infrastructure.

One important thing to note here is that HBase is a NoSQL DB and doesn't follow RDBMS conventions and terminologies. So, you might have to work a bit on your design initially.

Apart from HBase you have some other options as well, like **[Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)**, which is also a NoSQL DB.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop jobs use an [`InputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputFormat.html) to create the [`InputSplit`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/InputSplit.html)s. While the most examples use a file input and use HDFS fragments as input split, the concept is abstract and can be mapped to other inputs. A typical example is the already existing [`DataDrivenDBInputSplit`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/db/DataDrivenDBInputFormat.DataDrivenDBInputSplit.html) which represents a set of rows in a table. This kind of input formats/input splits are what is used by [Apache Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) (a command-line tool offering several commands) to read database inputs.

The gist of it is that  is absolutely possible to use DB as input for your job, you have to realize that what you will achieve is to unleash a cluster of computing nodes to slam your relational database with requests for a range of rows. It is *very* likely that your back end won't handle the load or, at best, handle it slowly. The power of Hadoop comes from the integration of processing with streamlined local storage access and you are asking explicitly to give it up.

So, if your goal is to move data between RDBMS and HDFS, Scoop got you covered in the following cases

- importing all tables from a database ([import-all-tables](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_all_tables_literal))
- importing one table ([sqoop-import](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_import_literal))
- importing part of a table (specific rows or specific columns) (respectively, [--where or --columns arguments](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_selecting_the_data_to_import))
- export data from HDFS to a relational DB ([sqoop-export](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_export_literal))

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop Core does not contain any database.

From the [Hadoop Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopIsNot)

> Databases are wonderful. Issue an SQL SELECT call against an
>   indexed/tuned database and the response comes back in milliseconds.
>   Want to change that data? SQL UPDATE and the change is in. Hadoop does
>   not do this.
>
> Hadoop **stores data in files**, and does **not index** them. If you want to
>   find something, you have to run a MapReduce job going through all the
>   data. This takes time, and means that **you cannot directly use Hadoop
>   as a substitute for a database**. Where Hadoop works is where the data
>   is too big for a database (i.e. you have reached the technical limits,
>   not just that you don't want to pay for a database license). With very
>   large datasets, the cost of regenerating indexes is so high you can't
>   easily index changing data. With many machines trying to write to the
>   database, you can't get locks on it. Here the idea of vaguely-related
>   files in a distributed filesystem can work.
>
> There is a high performance column-table database that runs on top of
>   Hadoop HDFS: **Apache HBase**. This is a great place to keep the results
>   extracted from your original data.

You can also use [Apache Hive](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Home) which gives you the feel of relational databases (although there are shortcomings) like MySQL. Behind the scenes it uses Mapreduce to help you leverage Hadoop for processing Big Data.
Please note that *Hive is not designed for OLTP workloads and does not offer real-time queries or row-level updates*